# Master page for markdowns

Tags: markdown

Does Markdown allow master page and sub pages setup ? If so how to do this. The scenario is to have the master page with default headers and footers and further details in the sub pages.

Comment: Markdown has no concept of pages. However, many of the tools that use Markdown do. Are you using any specific tools? If so, which ones?

Comment: No specific tools. I am using markdown in Git and using a browser to view. Where can I find an example of "markdown pages" in a tool ?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "pages." I assumed you were using a specific tool and needed to know what that tool was to know what you meant by "pages."

Comment: However, if you are using straight up Markdown (not wrapped in some other tool), then I will assume you mean "document" rather than "page". Each document (or file) is a standalone entity and has no knowledge of any other documents. It sounds like you are looking for a [static site generator](https://www.staticgen.com/) ([more here](https://staticsitegenerators.net/)), many of which wrap Markdown along with a template system, etc,